# how to calculate combined column mean value in R

Tags: r, mean

[image]

I want to make representative combined column and calculate mean.

for example, there are BILL_AMT(1,2,3,4,5,6).
but i want

> BILL_AMT <- which includes mean value of all BILL_AMT values.

how can i do?

Comment: Do you mean `colSums()`?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your data.

Comment: i did it. not colsums(). it was rowSums() .
thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a reproducible example of your data.

Just assuming what you're trying to do:

```
data <- data.frame(x = rep(1:10,1), y = rep(11:20, 1))

data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(mean = mean(x + y + ...))
```

Based on your comment: fill in your variables for `x + y + ...`

Comment: i mean make a new value which has mean value of all pay_AMTs.(pay_AMT1,2,3,4,5,6)
for example, pay_amt = 1 column, 10000 rows. each row has mean value of pay_amt(1,2,3,4,5,6)

Comment: Updated the answer